# How to search on specific words and have variable numbers

Tags: arrays, variables, search, numbers

I want to find some specific words and variable numbers next to it in a text file,
like that " People: 700 " you see that "People" is fixed but "700" can be any other number so I want to find this phrase which have any numbers , I tried using array but it didn't work for me. please some advice.

Comment: You said you tried an array.  Can you post your effort?

Answer (score 1):

You can match numbers with regex:

```
/People: (\d+)/
```

Answer (score 0):

In most of the programming languages, here is what you should do

```
1. Open the file for reading

2. While you can still read from the file

3. Read a line and store it to a variable

4. split the variable by delimiter (in your case, "People: " and " ")

5. get the value you want and store it into an array(or list)
```